# cant do push-ups

Tags: push-ups, beginners

I am 1.83m (6 feet) tall and my weight is 100kg.

I started running from last month and now I can run 2 miles with a 10 Min walking gap in between. One week ago I joined a gym. The problem is that on the first day I was asked to do push-ups 10 reps 3 set. I did it. On the second day I tried to do that again but felt as I had torn my tissues and was in excruciating pain. Then on the next day again  I tried to do push ups and couldn’t do even one. It is the sixth day today (with a one day gap in between ) and I still cant do even a single push-up.

I am ashamed of me now, embarrassed, what is wrong ? it feels as if its all locked. I just cant do push-up. everything else is happening. I don’t have any more pain in my body but still no push-ups, I am now reluctant to go to gym as I feel bad about myself. what to do ?

Comment: First off, stop feeling embarrassed. Go back to the gym, see the trainer you were working with, and explain the issue to them. From the description of what you felt it sounds like it's probably just DOMS (delayed onset muscle soreness), which is common when you start doing exercises your body isn't used to doing.

Comment: So will I be able to do push-ups normally with time without any special efforts ?

Comment: Do push-ups with your knees on the ground until you can.

Comment: Thank you guyz for the boost. No matter what now I will be doing 100 Soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off - stop feeling bad for yourself or embarrassed.  No one cares that you can't do a push up but you.  See a Dr. about the pain, sounds like you pulled or tore something (if it was just muscle soreness it would be gone within a couple of days).  Don't wait for it to get better - if it hasn't by day 3, it won't on its own.

Second - get back to the gym and walk on a treadmill, or do what ever you can do without further hurting the injured area.  Working out is 90% mental - you need to be consistent in your efforts. Work through the pain - but don't further injure yourself.  You have a lot of muscles and - I'm sure - can find some other exercise to do while you're healing.

Comment: So will I be able to do push-ups normally with time without any special efforts ?

Comment: I would imagine that you would UNLESS you have any long term medical condition (but I would highly suspect that you just pulled or tore something and time heals those things). Never give up

Comment: Thanks Mate I am hitting the Gym today and will kill it.

Answer (score 0):

What may also help you, that I still do, is wall push ups. It's a different approach but really helps. You can adjust the angle somewhat too. Try it.